# What is allowed in in-app purchases

Tags: actionscript-3, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase

I would like to have some info about apple's in-app purchases option.

I can't seem to find any place where they are explaining what is actually allowed. Becaus i wanted to make a digital bookstore with interactive books in asctionscript and offer the user interactive books (seperate swf files) via in-app purchases but apparently it is not allowed to have any code in your swf file, so that option is out of the window (btw if anyone knows of another option instead of swf files, please let me know).

Then have have thought of maybe starting in cocos2d but again i have no idea how i would distribute separate interactive books to the users. What are the options here?

So my questions are: what is allowed with in-app purchase, how can i offer interactive books (with posibility to click on elements and view animations etc) through in-app purchases.

And secondly and more important:

Would it be possible to do it via as3.0? Preferably i would like to do it through actionscript but can anyone tell me if its possible? Can i offer the user interactive books with elements that are pressable and animations etc through in-app purchases? And having all the books inside the application and unlocking them is not an option. I want to be able to provide books separatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely on the right track,

I think if you are looking to do an animated books series or something that's more interactive that a simple text format you should be fine using In-App Purchases for this. You'll only get in trouble if you're duplicating something iBooks can already provide.

You'll need an ANE to give you access to the InApp Purchases API from AS3, there are a few out there and I'll shamelessly plug mine:

http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#in-app-purchase

The major problem you'll have is actually distributing the additional content, as you may not be able to load in a swf and play it in a compiled iOS AIR application as you would a normal flash/AIR application. You'll have to do some research and see if you can create a player that just loads images and animation sequences (in xml or other).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't play swf files on the iPhone. Not without converting them to HTML5 or video. Which probably makes them non-interactive (not sure about HTML5).

2) Downloading any executable code to an iOS device is out of the question. There are some gray areas, for example downloaded Lua scripts which only contain data but due to their nature are executable code. It's a risk to do something like that, instead of just downloading XML or pure text/binary files.

3) Apple never tells you exactly what is allowed. They tell you what is not allowed, and even there they remain vague. There are always some gray areas and Apple reserves the right to define whether something in the grey area is acceptable to them or not. If you think your app is in the gray area, you need to have a backup plan in case Apple won't like it, or removes the app because they didn't initially find something wrong with it but later changed their mind.

4) Read the [iOS Developer Program License Agreement](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20120912.pdf) and the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). You may need to re-read some sentences because it's somewhat lawyer speak, though not really that hard to understand.

5) There are no guarantees. Best option: look at apps like yours and see if you can find your payment model implemented by other apps. If you find several such apps, it's most likely ok to do that. If you can't find any app that does something even remotely like you want to do it, beware.

6) I think you're on the wrong path. Use iBooks. Problem solved.